# Android ScrollView Will Not Scroll Anymore

Tags: java, android

I had successfully implemented a ScrollView which worked well when the keyboard would pop up on an input selection. The keyboard would cover some of the other buttons and text boxes but I was able to scroll through the page and gain access to the rest of my app layout. However now, (for some reason I do not know why) the scroll ability seems to have stopped functioning. I have not made any changes to the layout or the code. Can someone please shed some light on this issue? 
Log Cat even shows the following messages

```
03-12 10:03:28.040: D/BounceScrollRunnableDefault(6443): run(), TimeFraction=0.57, mBounceExtent=-1.3083752
03-12 10:03:28.040: D/BounceScrollRunnableDefault(6443): run(), TimeFraction=0.5725, mBounceExtent=-1.2707808
03-12 10:03:28.090: D/BounceScrollRunnableDefault(6443): run(), TimeFraction=0.695, mBounceExtent=-0.23490335
03-12 10:03:28.090: D/BounceScrollRunnableDefault(6443): run(), TimeFraction=0.6975, mBounceExtent=-0.22543272
03-12 10:03:28.140: D/BounceScrollRunnableDefault(6443): run(), TimeFraction=0.82, mBounceExtent=-0.016817156
03-12 10:03:28.190: D/BounceScrollRunnableDefault(6443): run(), TimeFraction=0.945, mBounceExtent=-4.4792334E-5
03-12 10:03:28.240: D/BounceScrollRunnableDefault(6443): run(), TimeFraction=1.07, mBounceExtent=-0.0
```

and I still do not see any scrolling on the screen.

Thanks.

Comment: You are going to need to give us a lot more information - the xml layout file, probably some of the code from the activity.

Comment: <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" > 

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >                                          This is where I start the Scroll View and I have everything following that layout.

Comment: I have the same (only on Tab10 android 3.2). isn't problem solved yet?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the layout_height values. Try this:

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" > 
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and still no luck, I was able to scroll before, but now it just stopped!

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a lower target SDK "match_parent" will not work so you should change it to "fill_parent"

Comment: match_parent will work with lower target SDKs as long as your project build target is API level 8 or higher.

Comment: I tried everything you guys suggested but still does not seem to work.

Comment: No even then it will not do it

Comment: could you edit your post and add the complete scrollview layout?